# Método retorna 0 en lugar del valor

Tags: java, array, poo, algoritmos, matriz

Tengo un método que me suma la filas de una matriz y las guarda en un vector, el método retorna dicho vector ahora, hice un método para imprimirlo y este método lo invoco en el switch. adjunto el código.

Aquí sumo las filas y las guardo en el vector.

```
 public int[] sumRows(int matrix[][]){
    int[] sumRow = new int[matrix.length];
    for(int i = 1; i < matrix.length; i++){
      for(int j = 0; j < matrix[i].length; j++){
        if(i < matrix.length - 1) 
          sumRow[i] += matrix[i][j];
      } // For j
    } // For i
    return sumRow;
  } // Fin de método
```

Aquí creo el método para imprimir el vector que retorna el método anterior.

```
public void showArray(int[] array){
for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,array[i]);
} // For
```

Por último acá invoco al método para que imprima el vector.

```
case 4:
    gui.showArray(test.sumRows(matrix));
    break;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La condición `if(i > matrix.length - 1)` nunca se va a cumplir porque es contradictoria a la condición del primer `for` `i < matrix.length`.

Si quitas la condición anterior vas a tener otro problema. La instrucción `sumRow[j] += matrix[i][j]` sumaría las columnas y no las filas.

Para que sume correctamente las filas debes cambiar el `for` interno por lo siguiente:

```
for(int j = 0; j < matrix[i].length; j++){
    sumRow[i] += matrix[i][j];
} // For j
```

Comment: listo tenía un 1 en la i, muchas gracias